# Nested sort, handling of NaN - untouched or sorted according to non-Nan column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, nan

I have a dataframe, containing NaNs, that I would like to groupby and sort based on two columns. The NaNs should not be on the bottom or top, but be sorted according to the non Nan column.

```
  Name  Upper  Lower
0    A   50.0   45.0
1    B    NaN    2.0
2    A   30.0    NaN
3    B   35.0    4.0
4    A   20.0   15.0
5    A    NaN   30.0

df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Lower','Upper'], ascending=False))

       Name  Upper  Lower
Name                     
A    0    A   50.0   45.0
     5    A    NaN   30.0
     4    A   20.0   15.0
     2    A   30.0    NaN
B    3    B   35.0    4.0
     1    B    NaN    2.0
```

What I want is for row 2 and 4 to switch places.

```
       Name  Upper  Lower
Name                     
A    0    A   50.0   45.0
     5    A    NaN   30.0
     2    A   30.0    NaN
     4    A   20.0   15.0
B    3    B   35.0    4.0
     1    B    NaN    2.0
```

So what I want is to sort on 'Lower' but if it is Nan then on 'Upper', they will never both be Nan for one row.

The bug pydata#3917 would have given me the functionality I want.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3917

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think that the bug you link to is slightly different from this use case and has been effectively fixed.

For your case you could use this hack:

```
df['new_column'] = df['Lower']
df.ix[pd.isnull(df['new_column']), 'new_column'] = df['Upper']
df.ix[pd.notnull(df['Lower']), 'rank'] = df.ix[pd.notnull(df['Lower']), 'Lower'].rank(ascending=False)
df.ix[pd.isnull(df['rank']) & pd.notnull(df['Upper']), 'rank'] = df.ix[pd.notnull(df['Upper']), 'Upper'].rank(ascending=False)
df['new_column'] = 1/df['new_column']
df.sort_values(['rank', 'new_column'], ascending=True)
```

Basically, make a new column with values from Lower. If Lower is missing, take the value from Upper. Also, rank all your values on lower and upper and combine the ranks using the same logic. Then sort on rank and if rank is the same sort on the new column.

Comment: Thank you for your response @amanbirs ! I might have misunderstood the bug. However, this soultion won't do it for me either. i.e. if row 2 was [A,49,Nan] (instead of [A,30,Nan]), I would want it to go below row 0 when sorted, not above as it does with this solution. The correct solution will probably not be far from this hack though.

Comment: No problem @maypay. Take a look at my editted solution. If I've understood your problem correctly this should work.

Comment: ok, made a lot of edits, this should work. Though it is a much more complex solution.